# Fine tuning leading for end notes chapter with \small fontsize

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, enumitem, endnotes, enotez

I'm preparing a book type project for which I'm trying to ensure the number of lines per page fits exactly the height of the typeblock, so that the lines are aligned on the two pages of the spread, and overleaf. With no `\raggedbottom` as you can presume.

For the main text, KOMA-Script's `typearea`, which I'm using, handles this flawlessly and I get a typeblock that fits an exact number of lines. However, I'm using `enotez` for an end notes chapter, which I've chosen to typeset in `\small` font size. And there's no reason that the `\textheight` calculated by `typearea` for `\normalsize` will fit an exact number of lines for whole pages typeset `\small`, and indeed, they don't.

I'd like to achieve the same alignment effect of the main text for the endnotes by slightly adjusting the leading, so that the end notes chapter also fits an exact number of lines. However, I can't seem to manage, thus the question.

The book's normal fontsize is `11pt`, using `scrbook` class with `DIV=12` and papersize `234mm:156mm`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=234mm:156mm, % small royal octavo
  DIV=12, % DIV calls '\typearea' and recalculates it.
  headings=normal, % less large headings.
}
```

The endnotes are set with `enotez` using a custom `enumitem` environment derived from `description`.  I set `parsep=\parskip,` and `itemsep=0pt,` to (supposedly) remove vertical space between the items, but allowing for some glue with `\parskip`. I'd expect this would correspond to the vertical spacing behavior of regular paragraphs (though I'm probably wrong).

```latex
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
  list-heading=\addchap{#1},
  list-style=customendnotes,
  split=chapter,
  backref,
  reset,
}

\newlist{customendnotes}{description}{4}
\setlist[customendnotes]{
  leftmargin=1em,
  listparindent=1em,
  labelsep=.2em,
  parsep=\parskip, % 0pt plus 1pt
  itemsep=0pt,
  % noitemsep, % sames as parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt => underfull vboxes...
}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{customendnotes}{list}
  {
    list-type = customendnotes,
    format = \small,
  }
```

Now, `\normalsize` gets a `10.95pt` font with `13.6pt` leading (`\baselineskip`), `\small` is `10pt` font with `12pt` leading. `typearea` sets a `\textheight` of `500.6pt`.

For the main text: `(500.6 + (13.6 - 11)) / 13.6 = 37`, a round 37.

For the end notes: `(500.6 + (12 - 10)) / 12 = 41.88333`.

So, the typeblock should be able to accommodate almost 42 lines, but 41 full ones. I'd like to increase the leading a little there, so that this page would fit exactly 41 lines.

So I thought: `((500.6 - (41*10)) / 40 ) + 10 = 12.265pt`  (inverting it `(500.6 + (12.265 - 10)) / 12.265 = 41`, which checks)

Thus, `12.265pt` is the theoretical leading I want. I try to set it with `\linespread`. `{\small \linespread{1.02208333333}\selectfont \the\baselineskip}` gives me `12.26495pt`, close enough.

However, the problem is that the above reasoning is somewhere flawed, for the end notes pages, typeset in `\small`, do not fit 41 lines at all, but 39 or 40, depending on the case. As a result, of course the lines are misaligned between the two pages of the spread (I am giving some glue to `parsep`, but  removing it would just result in underfull vboxes). I presume I'm missing some vertical parameter of the list environment, but I really can pin down why. And, not understanding where the vertical space comes from, I fail to get my numbers right.

So, the question is, why does this page not fit 41 lines, as I'd expect? And how could I calculate (and set) correctly the leading for this chapter's pages so that if fits an exact number of lines in the typeblock?

A MWE example putting things together.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=234mm:156mm, % small royal octavo
  DIV=12, % DIV calls '\typearea' and recalculates it.
  headings=normal, % less large headings.
}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
  list-heading=\addchap{#1},
  list-style=customendnotes,
  split=chapter,
  backref,
  reset,
}

\newlist{customendnotes}{description}{4}
\setlist[customendnotes]{
  leftmargin=1em,
  listparindent=1em,
  labelsep=.2em,
  parsep=\parskip, % 0pt plus 1pt
  itemsep=0pt,
  % noitemsep, % sames as parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt => underfull vboxes...
}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{customendnotes}{list}{
  list-type = customendnotes,
  format = \small,
}

\AddToHook{env/customendnotes/begin}{\linespread{1.02208333333}\selectfont}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testchapter {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 25 }
      {
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][1-5]}
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][6-14]}
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][15-16]}
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][17-25]}
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][26-28]}
        \lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[][29-40]}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\thefontsize\normalsize % 10.95pt
\thefontsize\small %10pt

\the\textheight % 500.60022pt

\the\baselineskip % 13.6pt

{\small \the\baselineskip} % 12pt

{\small \linespread{1.02208333333}\selectfont \the\baselineskip} % 12.26495pt

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\testchapter

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\testchapter

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I think I have found the main culprit, but not all of it. `enotez`, to support `hyperref` links, adds a raised link with a hardcoded height of `1em`, and this accounts for the spaces between items I was finding. This can be fixed using:

```latex
\cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_write_list_number:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_hyperfootnotes_bool
      {
        % \box_move_up:nn {1em} { \hbox:n { \hypertarget {enz.#1} { } } }
        \Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget {enz.#1} { } }
      }
    \tl_use:N \l__enotez_list_number_format_tl
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { \l__enotez_hyperfootnotes_bool }
      { \l__enotez_hyperbackref_bool }
      {
        \exp_args:Nnx
        \hyperlink {enz.#1.backref}
          { \exp_not:V \l__enotez_endnote_mark_tl }
      }
      {
        \str_if_eq:neTF {a} { \prop_item:Nn \g__enotez_endnote_man_prop {#1} }
          { \prop_item:Nn \g__enotez_endnote_mark_prop {#1} }
          { \exp_not:V \l__enotez_endnote_mark_tl }
      }
  }
```

With this, now the 41 lines do fit. However, if I set the `\linespread` to the theoretical value I had calculated (`\linespread{1.02208333333}`, to achieve leading of `12.265pt`) the 41st line jumps to the next page again. Trial and error suggests the highest I can go is `\linespread{1.0199966}` (resulting in `\baselineskip` of `12.23987pt`). I'd still love to know why the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjustment of the raised hyperlinks of `enotez` was suggested upstream (https://github.com/cgnieder/enotez/issues/42), has already been implemented and will be available on the next release (the current is v0.10d of 2022/01/04).